# Creating and assigning tasks in Outlook from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am attempting to create a service desk tool in Excel, and the way I am thinking of making it easy for the admin to assign them would be to use the tasks in Outlook.

The admin person would receive the email, fill out a line in Excel, then click on a button to open a new task in Outlook, with fields pre-filled out. Then they would drag and drop the email as an attachment.

However, I am trying to get the assigned to email address pre-filled from a value in the spreadsheet. Assign doesn't seem to work, and neither does Recipient. Does anyone have any ideas why not? This is the code that I have so far:

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem

 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

 With OutTask
    .Assign = Cells(2, "G")
    .Subject = "Service Request" & Cells(2, "A")
    .StartDate = Cells(2, "H")
    .DueDate = Cells(2, "H") + Cells(2, "I")
    .ReminderTime = .DueDate - 1
    .Body = "Please see the attached email for a service request assigned to you."
    .Display
 End With

Set OutTsk = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the sample here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869880(v=office.15).aspx
provided by microsoft
Assign is a method and you are using it like a property.
Receipients are a collection, so you have to add them, again you cant assign them like a property
Also you have misspelt `OutTsk`  at the end. What I would do as a matter of course when programming is turn on `Option Explicit` this stops misspelt variables from ruining your day.

So try something like this

```
Sub tasks()
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutTask As Outlook.TaskItem

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutTask = OutApp.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add(Cells(2, "C"))
myRecipient.Resolve

 If myRecipient.Resolved Then
    With OutTask
       .Subject = "Service Request" & Cells(2, "A")
       .StartDate = Cells(2, "H")
       .DueDate = Cells(2, "H") + Cells(2, "I")
       .ReminderTime = .DueDate - 1
       .Body = "Please see the attached email for a service request assigned to you."
       .Assign
       .Display
    End With
End If
Set OutTask = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! However, I am getting a 438 error on the following line which I can't seem to resolve?

`Set myRecipient = OutTask.Recipients.Add(Cells(2, "C"))`

Comment: I assume that you have a valid recipient name in Cell C2? if not then specify the valid cell that contains the recipient information. This line will fail if that cell is blank say.

Comment: I've tried adding an email address and a users name in both the spreadsheet cell and the code without a reference to the spreadsheet. Still no go on either...

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Outlook Object Library? You will need to do that for this to work. If it is not there then choose <Tools><References> and go down to <Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library> click on the Check Mark and then OK to add it. To inspect a library to see what it supports,  press [F2] then choose <all Libraries> and go down to the Outlook library to inspect.

Comment: Sure have. Outlook 15.0. I've been studying the browser and can't see where this is going wrong...surely I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Hi James, this is a tricky one. I would suspect it is something to do with the dlls and versioning. From checking around n the net this error Run-time error '438' "Object doesn't support this property or method ... " seems to be 32/64 bit related or up/down version related. Though I am using v16, i understand that adding recipients has been available at lesat since 2007. is the method in your object library?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm running 32 bit on the work PC. Method is definetly in the object library. I've just been looking at the MSDN site, and it says that the value for Recipients in TaskItem is read only. Wonder if this is the issue? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn352390.aspx

Comment: I've managed to circumvent this issue by using SendKeys. Not ideal, but might be the only way to get this to work on my setup :-(

Comment: SendKeys is lateral thinking alright. Yes the Recipients property is read only as it is a collection. However the Recipients Object should have an Add method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866751.aspx