# (Outlook) Recurring monthly email sent 2 days before the last Wednesday?

Tags: vba, outlook

I manually send an email out on the last Monday of every month that is before the last Wednesday of the month. I essentially want email replies *on* the last Wednesday of every month and send the email 2 days prior on the Monday for notice.

Can this be solved with a VBA/Macro? It can be a meeting or email or anything so long as an email with the same canned text gets sent 2 days before that last Wednesday of each month. Thank you!

Comment: You can trigger mail with a reminder on any item that allows reminders. A task may be appropriate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859813/send-email-reminder-when-task-occurs. Create the tasks on the last Wednesday then set the reminder two days before. It could all be kept in Outlook VBA but setting up the dates in Excel may be easier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689775/creating-and-assigning-tasks-in-outlook-from-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be solved with Outlook VBA. You can set up a reminder in Outlook which you can handle and send out your emails 2 days prior the event for notice. Here is sample code that shows how to handle reminders:

```
Dim WithEvents myolapp As Outlook.Application 
 
Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set myolapp = Outlook.Application  
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myolapp_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object) 
  ' here you can send emails to notice 2 days before
  ' or just display the source item
  Item.Display 
End Sub
```

The `AppointmentItem`, `MailItem`, `ContactItem`, or `TaskItem` associated with the reminder is passed as a parameter. If the appointment associated with the reminder is a recurring appointment, `Item` is the specific occurrence of the appointment that displayed the reminder, not the master appointment. So, I think it is more convenient to create a recurring appointment with a reminder set up.

To handle incoming responses you need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class in Outlook. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.  Use the Entry ID to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Finally, I'd suggest starting from the [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) article.